# Need Help with Honda Engine Swap

Tags: honda, civic

I have a '98 Honda Civic EXi with D15Z4 16 valve SOHC, in which I installed a D16A7 SOHC 16 valve engine, so I would like to know what kind ECU compatible with this engine and the schematic for wiring of detail plug Ignition Distributor.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may want to reread your question. You have some mismatches in your terminology. You may also want to register your account so you can follow this more easily. I'm sure you'll have a lot of questions in the future as an engine swap as you've suggested is not without its perils.

Comment: Re-word this a bit better. I'm a Honda master-tech and have done plenty of B and D series swaps. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Explain it better and we can help you more.

Comment: Looking on [Honda D engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_D_engine) entry on Wikipedia, it appears that appears that the D15Z4 uses a P2C/P2E ECU and the D16A7 uses a PM6 or P27.

Comment: Is this the same question as mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/35624/…? They sound similar but details aren't quite the same. I think it would be good to merge and then delete one of them if they are the same question.

Comment: Did u get the solution ? I have Same question . I want to swap my D15z4 to D16A7. Can we use old ECU with new one ? Do share your experience. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for having an off topic question but does that single camshaft have 16 lobes each operating its own valve or how is the camshaft designed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECU help required](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/36654/ecu-help-required)